# Subquery returned more than 1 value when trigger run

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create DML triggers to do certain things on delete and update in 2 tables,

I have 3 tables: `payments_yearly`, `payments_yearly_details`,`cheque_in`

`payments_yearly` table have all payments and those payments have details( payments methods and values) saved in `payments_yearly_details`, the payments method can be cash, visa, cheque. cheque details will be saved in the `cheque_in` table.

[image]

I have a query that gets the payment info + the sum value from details as this:

```
SELECT dbo.payments_yearly.ID, SUM(dbo.payments_yearly_details.value) AS value, dbo.payments_yearly.note,
dbo.payments_yearly.date, dbo.payments_yearly.app_user FROM dbo.payments_yearly INNER JOIN
dbo.payments_yearly_details ON dbo.payments_yearly.ID = dbo.payments_yearly_details.pay_id where payments_yearly.con_id=@con_id
GROUP BY dbo.payments_yearly.ID, dbo.payments_yearly.con_id, dbo.payments_yearly.note, dbo.payments_yearly.date, dbo.payments_yearly.app_user
```

so I Created a trigger to delete all the cheques from the `cheque_in` table if the user deletes a payment from the `payments_yearly` table and my trigger as bellow:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[delete_cheque_after_delete_payment] on [dbo].[payments_yearly]
AFTER Delete
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @payid as int
set @payid= (select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id=(SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted) and method =N'شيك')
Delete from cheque_in where pay_id =@payid

END
```

but when I delete any payment from the `payments_yearly` the cheque didn't delete also, So I don't know where is the mistake here.
I tried to change the `@pay_id` value to a static value from the `cheque_in` table like `25` but it conflicts with another trigger that I created to update the `payments_yearly_details` table value of the payment method cheque "because this value may come from multiple cheques"  when user change a cheque value or deleted a cheque related to the payment, and this trigger as bellow:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_payments_yearly_detailson_cheque_UpdateDelete] on [dbo].[cheque_in]
after UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM payments_yearly_details WHERE ID=(SELECT deleted.pay_id FROM deleted)) 
BEGIN
Declare @value as decimal(10,2)
set @value= (SELECT SUM(cheque_in.cheque_value) from cheque_in where cheque_in.pay_id = (SELECT deleted.pay_id FROM deleted))
Update payments_yearly_details set value=@value where ID=(SELECT deleted.pay_id FROM deleted)
END
END
```

this trigger working good and its updating the payment value when deleting a cheque or update a cheque value, but its conflict with the first trigger with this error message :
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated.'`

I'm new to triggers, So my question is: why is my first trigger not working? and why I'm getting the error message on the second trigger if I assigned a static value(which is in the cheque and in this case my trigger working) to the first trigger.

Thank you.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. A trigger fires once per _statement_, not _row_. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
 (select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id=(SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted) and method =N'شيك')
```

If this statement returns more than one value you get the error you mentioned. You cant do this with scalar sub queries. I mean outside of the fact the system throws hard error for it - think about it - my variable now is equal to this and that? That doesnt make sense.

You can do cheap hacks to fix it like using DISTINCT or GROUP BY but that doesnt fix the logical side of things.

*EDIT*

so you just pointed out your issue:

```
 (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)
```

if you delete more than one ID at a time youre going to get this error.

*EDIT 2*

So now we know you have multiple id's per row and we know that how youre trying to assign to a variable doesnt work, so try this.

Chnage this:

```
Declare @payid as int
set @payid= (select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id IN (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted) and method =N'شيك')
Delete from cheque_in where pay_id =@payid
```

To this:

```
Delete from cheque_in where pay_id IN ((select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id IN ((SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)) and method =N'شيك'))
```

Comment: but If I run this query like this: `select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id=(27) and method =N'شيك'` I will get one result which is '25'.
and why my first trigger not working in the first place, can you see anything wrong with it ??

Comment: Ohh now it makes sense, what do you think is the best approach to complish this ??

Comment: Turn it inot a correlated subquery - so that each result set is tied to the outer query, which will prevent your query from bombing.

Comment: you could also turn that comparison operator to IN instead of =

Comment: why I can't get results from this query ?? `set @payid= (select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id in (SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted) and method =N'شيك')`, if I use it in trigger the trigger will do nothing but if I replace it with static number `39` the trigger works fine.

Comment: As Ive state before - you cant assign a variable multiple values like that.,

Comment: Correct, but this query should return one value onley

Comment: Still not working, this query `(select ID from payments_yearly_details where pay_id IN ((SELECT deleted.ID FROM deleted)) and method =N'شيك')` should return '47' for my current data, If I change the trigger to this `Delete from cheque_in where cheque_in.pay_id =47` it will work fine, but when I change it to the query nothing happened and no cheque will be deleted.

Comment: you need to alter the one that is bombing to give you error output so we can see what the actual issue is.

Comment: I deleted one trigger to stop the error, I'm trying to make the first trigger working but the query not working or not returning the ID and I don't know why, if I add a number instead of the query that supposes to return the ID the trigger will work fine and this is my problem now.